# Smoothing flash animation

Tags: flash, tween, motion

I've got a MovieClip containing several child clips (images and text).

I'm trying to scale this parent clip very slowly - from 102% down to 98% - this works, however the child movie clips are all scaling a bit jerkily - like they're trying to stick to pixels or something. What's the cure for this?

The scaling is done by using a motion tween on the timeline by the way. I've tried to tick "Cache Bitmap" but that makes no difference.

If I used the 3D motion tween, there is no jerkyness. But I need to publish to flash 9, so can't use that!

Cheers

Guy

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the following:
 - convert all text fields to bitmap snapshots
  - if you 'must' use text fields, make sure that antiAliasType is set to AntiAliasType.NORMAL
 - set smoothing equal to true on all bitmaps
 - set pixelSnapping to PixelSnapping.NEVER on all bitmaps

I wouldn't set cacheAsBitmap to true b/c you are scaling the clip which will cause the player to redraw the cache every frame.

Good luck!

Comment: yep - textfield to antialias for animation, plus images to smoothing = on. doh!